# Different frames on different devices?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a top-bar on several of my websites, that is shown via iframe, however it looks awful on mobile devices, so i was wondering if i could put it inside a div and then target the div through css with display none if the screen is smaller than a certain size.

The ideal thing would be to show one iframe on desktop and another on mobile devices.

I'm thinking something like:

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 320px) 
#div {display:none;}
```

I have absolutely no idea of how to display an iframe with a different source, which is what would be the ideal solution for me.

Hope you guys can help me

Comment: Try `@media only screen and (max-device-width : 320px) {
#div {display:none;} }` Although you can just target the `iframe` straight away.

Answer (score 0):

```
@media handheld and (max-device-width : 320px) 
{

#div {display:none;}

}
```

Check your device width too and use the same in max-device-width feature.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display a different URL based on the screen width. I would suggest making two iframes, one of them on display: none and the other on display: block. And then switch their display-properties when the screen is smaller than x px.

Something like:

```
<style>
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
#mobile-iframe {
    display: none;
}
@media handheld and (max-device-width : 320px) {
    #normal-iframe {
        display: none;        
    }
    #mobile-iframe {
        display: block;
    }
}
</style>

<iframe id="normal-iframe" src="http://test.com"></iframe>
<iframe id="mobile-iframe" src="http://test.com/help/"></iframe>
```

Experiment with it here: http://jsfiddle.net/zTzRA/